# Building ordered JSON string (GSON library)

Tags: java, json, gson

Below is a simple example of how my JSON should look like . The object has string values for first name and last name, a number value for age and an array value of phone number objects.

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

Here is my code:

```
        // creating JSONObject
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        // putting data to JSONObject
        jsonObj.put("firstName", "John");
        jsonObj.put("lastName", "Smith");
        jsonObj.put("age", 25);

        // for phone numbers, first create JSONArray
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

        //  create LinkedHashMap
        Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("type", "home");
        map.put("number", "212 555-1234");

        // adding map to list
        jsonArr.put(map);

        map.put("type", "fax");
        map.put("number", "212 555-1234");

        // adding map to list
        jsonArr.put(map);

        // putting phoneNumbers to JSONObject
        jsonObj.put("phoneNumbers", jsonArr);

        // Instantiate a new Gson instance.
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // writing JSON to file:"JSONExample.json" in cwd
        String json = gson.toJson(jsonObj);
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
{
"map":
{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName":"Smith",
"age":25,
"phoneNumbers":
{
"myArrayList":
[
{
"map":
       {
        "type":"home",
        "number":"212 555-1234"
       }
},
{
"map":
       {  
       "type":"fax",
       "number":"212 555-1234"
       }
}
]
}
}
}
```

How can I ged rid of "myArrayList" and "map" in the JSON string?

**UPDATE**
I changed last part of the code:

```
// writing JSON to file:"JSONExample.json" in cwd
        String json = jsonObj.toString();
```

And it works. But When I modify "firstName" to "first" like this:

```
// putting data to JSONObject
        jsonObj.put("first", "John");
        jsonObj.put("last", "Smith");
        jsonObj.put("age", 25);
```

I'm getting disordered string which is weird.

```
{"last":"Smith","first":"John","age":25,"phoneNumbers":[{"type":"home","number":"212 555-1234"},{"type":"fax","number":"212 555-1234"}]}
```

I thought GSON library keeps the string ordered.

Comment: why don't you just `String json = jsonObj.toString()`

Comment: It works great.

Comment: Ok, this is weird when I make few changes to code. For example If I change "firstName":"John", to "first": "John" I'm getting unordered string. Do you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: JSONObject is an **unordered** collection of name/value pairs.

Comment: What you're trying to do does not make much sense as long as you mix libraries getting unexpected results. There is NO such thing in Gson like `JSONObject`: Gson classes use a different naming like `JsonObject`. Next, `org.json.JSONObject` seems to follow the JSON specification that defines JSON objects unordered (as told above) by using a HashMap (at least for the implementation I'm peeking in). Gson, on other hand, uses insert-defined order with a custom implementation of linked hash map preserving the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [elegant-json](https://github.com/admin1475963/elegant-json). This library by default save order of elements.
This JSON:

```json
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

can be made by this code:

```java
   new JsonObject()
       .add("firstName", new JsonString("John"))
       .add("lastName", new JsonString("Smith"))
       .add("age", new JsonInt(25))
       .add(
          "phoneNumbers", 
           new JsonArray()
               .add(
                   new JsonObject()
                       .add("type", new JsonString("home"))
                       .add("number", new JsonString("212 555-1234"))
               )
               .add(
                   new JsonObject()
                       .add("type", new JsonString("home"))
                       .add("number", new JsonString("212 555-1234"))
               )
       ).toJson();
```

**Note:** JSON by definition is not ordered. So try not to depend on order of elements